# Convert List<string> to Json Array on client ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a string List on server that Im sending to a partial view.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
```

On Client Side I'm converting the list to json like this:

```
var stringList = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.Model.StringList)));
alert(stringList );
```

The alert reply is: `1,2` and I should get `["1","2"]`.

Any clue on how to deal with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Go to your web browser's console, and enter `alert(["1", "2"])`. Hit Enter. It will alert `1,2` because `["1", "2"].toString() === "1,2"`.  You should try to `console.log(stringList)` and see what it really is -- perhaps you already have what you seek.

Answer (score 4):

What your asking for is a plain and simple array, not json.

That aside, just append brackets around it:

```
var stringList = [@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.Model.StringList)))];
alert(stringList );
```

This works for numbers but if you intend to use it with real string values (like words or such) you'll need a different approach. It isn't clear if you intent to use this with numbers treated as strings as your example or not.

Comment: I don't see why you're telling him to manually add square brackets. Json.Encode already adds square brackets.

Comment: No, in this case Json.Encode outputs a comma separated list of values without the brackets. The brackets would only be output if the object being encoded was something that had a property that was a list of objects. This is an older answer that was created over a year and a half ago, newer versions of MVC may have changes this behavior.