# Call JavaScript function with Razor syntax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently working on an ASP.Net MVC application.
From my database, I have created three dictionaries and stored them inside a View Model.

After populating said dictionaries with some logic in the controller, I'm accessing these dictionaries in my View via `@Model`

After manipulating these dictionaries, I need to send the data to a JS function to apply some logic to a  JS library called [DHtmlxScheduler](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/)

I have read about the Razor syntax using  `@:` and am currently using this method to send two string arrays. when trying to access these arrays in the JS function, they only appear to hold `System.String[]`

Here is the code:

```
var weekArray;
var engArray;

@foreach(var week in Model.WeeklySchedule)
{
    var key = week.Key;
    var values = week.Value.ToArray();
    var eng = Model.EngineerSchedule.Where(k => k.Key == key).Select(v => v.Value).ToArray();
    string test = "hello";

    @: gatherTimes('@values', '@eng');
}

function gatherTimes(values, engs)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        alert(values[i]);
    }

    //alert(values);
    //alert(engs);

    //weekArray[weekArray.length] = values;
    //engArray[engArray.length] = engineers;
}
```

I eventually plan on looping through the arrays, they hold information about time slots and engineer IDs. If there is any more information I may provide, I will do my best to do so.

Comment: you need [`Json.Encode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert List<string> to Json Array on client ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959770/convert-liststring-to-json-array-on-client-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to encode the list to JSON using JSON.Encode. Here is an example:

```
@{    
   // C# collection
   var collection= new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
 }

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   // encode C# collection to JSON, set to javascript variable
   var arr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(collection))
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   {
      console.log(arr[i]); // Output is A  B  C
   }
</script>
```

In your case it would be like so:

```
@: gatherTimes('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(values))', '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(eng))');
```